# Openstack Single Installer Fails - keystone: hook failed: "config-changed"

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud

Tried steps given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html) on Ubuntu14.04 LTS. I'm Hitting keystone: hook failed: "config-changed" error.  I could see same problem reported [#961](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/961), and the suggested solution 
is to try from ppa:cloud-installer/experimental, but it seems to be not working. Please confirm will this work or we have other ways to mitigate the issue. Thanks